# Sytling DateTime-Local Calendar Clear Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to style or remove this clear button from the calendar pop up that comes with the html5 datetime picker? It is not clearing my field and would like to remove or edit it since it is not working correctly.

[image]

Here is the input html

```
<label for="rowKeyStartDate">Start Date/Time: </label>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput id="rowKeyStartDate" type="datetime-local" step="0.001" formControlName="rowKeyStartDate" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Btw, the picker is different in different browsers (Firefox), so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to check all browsers

Answer (score 2):

Implicitly one way the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button works is to add a hidden `<button>` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input id="el" type="datetime-local">
    <button onclick="javascript:el.value=''" hidden></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this works for the clear button that shows on the actual input, I am looking for a way to get to the clear button on the calendar pop up. Thanks for the info though

Comment: Songs have been written for [this behavior](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087501).